# HTML can't find JavaScript file at all

Tags: javascript, html

This is the call on the HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript" src='../js/scripts.js'></script>`

And this is the way I'm using to verify it works:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        window.alert('Hello world!');
    }
});
```

On the Home page it works effortlessly, but in that next page it does not work, feels like it's not triggering again to refresh the document that the js is on.

The file structure for this is:

- data

  - js

    - scripts.js
  - pages

    - secondPage.html
- homePage.html

I've tried to put the script tag on the bottom, but still no answer from the js file

Comment: You use a relative path `../data/js/scripts.js` but the homePage and secondPage are in different relative positions according to your information. Try change it to `/data/js/scripts.js` in all your files. And you don´t need to specify the tyoe. `<script src='/data/js/scripts.js'></script>` should be enough.

Comment: From `homePage.html`: `src="./data/js/scripts.js"` and from `secondPage.html`: `src="../js/scripts.js"`

Comment: @somethinghere From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type) "Authors are encouraged to omit the attribute if the script refers to JavaScript code rather than specify a MIME type." and from the [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) "Authors should omit the type attribute instead of redundantly setting it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for `scripts.js` on `secondPage.html` should be `../js/scripts.js`, since both are in the same folder. (`data`)

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src='../js/scripts.js'></script>
```

Note: but as someone stated in the comments, you should favor referencing via its absolute path. (`/data/js/scripts.js`)

Comment: Yes, I know but that's not working

Answer (score 0):

With the home page `homePage.html` at the "bottom", when it looks for the file with instructions `../data/js/scripts.js`, it goes up one level (the folder with everything here inside it), then looks for the `data` folder, then the `js` folder, then the `script.js` file.

With the second page `secondPage.html`, it also goes up one level, but this time that level above is the `pages` folder. It tries to search for `data` but can't find it.

If you'd like to keep the file structure you already have laid out in the question, **modify your script element, in that second page, to be `<script type="text/javascript" src='../../../data/js/scripts.js'></script>`** as this will go to the root folder before looking for the data folder.

Additionally, make sure that your `<script></script>` element is present in that second page.

Comment: This isn't working, the same problem keeps on happening